# Differential equation and For loop in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to optimize some kind of process in Mathematica. I did it without any problems in Matlab and now I'm trying to do the same in Mathematica which I don't know at all. I'm trying to find the best value of variable u for my proces, but that's not what I'm going to ask. My code at least should print eleven values of variable 'wynik' but it doesn't. I suppose that I've got some stupid and minor mistake in syntax, but as I've said earlier - I'm new at Mathematica environment. Any thoughts?

```
For[u == 1, u <= 1, u == u + 0.1,  
    s = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == u*(10*x2[t] - x1[t]),  x1[0] == 1,   
                x2'[t] == u*(x1[t] - 10*x2[t]) - (1 - u)*x2[t], x2[0] == 0}, 
                 {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 1}];  
    wynik == 1 - Evaluate[{x1[1] /. s} + {x2[1] /. s}]; 
    Print[wynik]]
```

Comment: But you wrote `For[u == 1, u <= 1,` so how do you expect this to run 11 times? try may be  `For[u = 0, u <= 1`.....  (note also difference between `=` and `==`). These are not the same in Mathematica. see help on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html also better to use `Do` if you need to make explicit loops.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: As far as I understand your code, I think you should really not use `For`, and probably not even `Print` (I admit, I used it quite a bit 20 years ago when I was green). Instead, you should consider `Function`s, `Table`s, or other functional concepts. My personal preference is to avoid imperative programming and explicit loops whenever practical. Mathematica is really suited for this approach, and as a result you'll feel a lot less like you're fighting against it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually your system can be solved exactly:

```
s = DSolve[
           {x1'[t] ==  u (10 x2[t] - x1[t]),
            x2'[t] == -u (10 x2[t] - x1[t]) - (1 - u) x2[t],
            x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 0},
           {x1, x2}, t];
sol = {x1, x2} /. First@s;
Plot3D[Through[sol[t]] /. u -> v, {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So your `wynik` behavior is

```
Plot[1 - Plus @@ (Through[sol[t]] /. u -> v) /. t -> 1, {v, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the maximum is at

```
NMaximize[1 - Plus @@ (Through[sol[t]] /. u -> v) /. t -> 1, v]

( {0.0391638, {v -> 0.3144}} *)
```

Comment: One more questiion. How can I obtain the maximum value of wynik and which u responds to that?

Answer (score 4):

Corrected version of the For-loop:

```
For[u = 0, u <= 1, u = u + 0.1, 
 s = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == u*(10*x2[t] - x1[t]), x1[0] == 1, 
    x2'[t] == u*(x1[t] - 10*x2[t]) - (1 - u)*x2[t], x2[0] == 0}, {x1, 
    x2}, {t, 0, 1}];
 wynik = 1 - Evaluate[{x1[1] /. s} + {x2[1] /. s}];
 Print[wynik]]

(* {{0.}}
{{0.0253818}}
{{0.0360628}}
{{0.0391236}}
{{0.037966}}
{{0.0343092}}
{{0.0290704}}
{{0.0227663}}
{{0.0157036}}
{{0.00807336}}
{{-2.22045*10^-16} *)
```

As Nasser said your use of `=` and `==` was wrong.